# Round Robin for Team Matches

Tags: combinatorics

My question came from the Bridge-game (Teams). This is what happens:

Ideally, there are 4 pairs (A,B,C,D). We have 2 tables. In every table, there are 2 pairs. One pair is sitting in the North-South orientation and the other pair in the East-West orientation. Each Team consists of 2 pairs. So, assuming that Team 1 consists of pairs A,B and Team 2 consists of pairs C,D, this is how they should be sitting:

```
Table #    N-S    E-W
1           A      C
2           D      B
```

or

```
Table #    N-S    E-W
1           A      D
2           C      B
```

Let's call the first match (A,B,C,D) and the second one (A,B,D,C). i.e (you, your teammates, your opponents in the same table as you, your opponents in the other table)

Assuming now that you don't have a fixed teammate. 
Let's also assume that we only care about the following:

- You should have played with all other pairs as teammate
- You should have played with all other pairs as opponents on the same table

This is how 3 rounds could be played:

```
Round #    Match
1          (A,B,C,D)
2          (A,C,D,B)
3          (A,D,B,C)
```

In my problem, I have 5 pairs (A,B,C,D,E). This is how a schedule should be:

```
Round #    Match        Not playing this round (Bye)
1          (A,B,C,D)    E
2          (A,C,?,?)    ?
3          (A,D,?,?)    ?
4          (A,E,?,?)    ?
5          (B,?,?,?)    A
```

but I cannot find any combination fulfilling my requirements.

Is there any math background behind this kind of problems?

Comment: Does http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm help?

Comment: no, @PeterTaylor. This is the classic Round-Robin. Many schedule generators can be found. Mine is a special case, where I cannot find a solution. And I was wondering if I could prove(approach) with maths that there is no solution

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be formulated as an instance of a problem called *exact set cover*, and then it's relatively simple to show that it does indeed have no solution.

We start by listing out the things that we want to happen. I'm using the notation `A+B` to mean "A and B play in the same team" and `AxB` to mean "A and B play against each other at the same table". Then there are 10 pairs from 5 teams, and two things we want to do with each pair, so 20 things which we want to happen.

```
A+B A+C A+D A+E B+C B+D B+E C+D C+E D+E AxB AxC AxD AxE BxC BxD BxE CxD CxE DxE
```

Any match satisfies precisely 4 of the requirements, because there are two teams and two tables. We can draw up a full table of all the possible matches, showing which requirements they satisfy.

```
A+B A+C A+D A+E B+C B+D B+E C+D C+E D+E AxB AxC AxD AxE BxC BxD BxE CxD CxE DxE
.                           .               .               .
.                           .                   .       .
.                               .           .                   .
.                               .                   .   .
.                                   .           .               .
.                                   .               .       .
    .               .                   .                           .
    .               .                           .       .
    .                   .               .                               .
    .                   .                           .   .
    .                               .           .                       .
    .                               .               .               .
        .       .                       .                           .
        .       .                           .               .
        .               .               .                                   .
        .               .                           .       .
        .                       .           .                               .
        .                       .                   .               .
            .   .                       .                               .
            .   .                           .                   .
            .       .                   .                                   .
            .       .                           .               .
            .               .               .                               .
            .               .                   .                       .
                .                   .                       .           .
                .                   .                           .   .
                    .           .                       .                   .
                    .           .                               .   .
                        .   .                           .                   .
                        .   .                               .           .
```

Now the exact set cover problem consists in selecting some *rows* such that every *column* contains precisely one `.`. Since the setup is completely symmetric, let's select the first row, delete the rows which have a `.` in the same column, and tally up how many `.`s remain in the other columns.

```
A+B A+C A+D A+E B+C B+D B+E C+D C+E D+E AxB AxC AxD AxE BxC BxD BxE CxD CxE DxE
*                           *               *               *
    .               .                   .                           .
    .               .                           .       .
    .                   .               .                               .
    .                   .                           .   .
    .                               .           .                       .
    .                               .               .               .
        .       .                       .                           .
        .               .               .                                   .
        .                       .                   .               .
            .   .                       .                               .
            .       .                   .                                   .
            .       .                           .               .
                .                   .                           .   .
                    .           .                       .                   .
                    .           .                               .   .

    6   3   3   3   6   3       3   3   6       3   3   3       3   6   3   3
```

Now there isn't quite so much symmetry. We'll pick a row (`A+D`) with as few dots as possible (3), and consider the three cases.

#### Case 1

```
A+B A+C A+D A+E B+C B+D B+E C+D C+E D+E AxB AxC AxD AxE BxC BxD BxE CxD CxE DxE
*                           *               *               *
    .               .                           .       .
    .                   .                           .   .
    .                               .           .                       .
        *       *                       *                           *
            .       .                           .               .
                    .           .                       .                   .

    3       1       3   1       1   1           3   1   3       1       1   1
```

#### Case 2

```
A+B A+C A+D A+E B+C B+D B+E C+D C+E D+E AxB AxC AxD AxE BxC BxD BxE CxD CxE DxE
*                           *               *               *
    .               .                           .       .
    .                               .           .                       .
    .                               .               .               .
        *               *               *                                   *
            .       .                           .               .
                .                   .                           .   .
                    .           .                               .   .

    3       1   1   3           1   3           3   1   1       3   3   1
```

#### Case 3

```
A+B A+C A+D A+E B+C B+D B+E C+D C+E D+E AxB AxC AxD AxE BxC BxD BxE CxD CxE DxE
*                           *               *               *
    .               .                           .       .
    .                   .               .                               .
    .                               .           .                       .
        *                       *                   *               *
            .   .                       .                               .
            .       .                   .                                   .
            .       .                           .               .

    3       3   1   3   1           1   3       3       1       1       3   1
```

In each of those three cases there are a number of columns which only have one option left, so we have to choose those rows. But then we end up with some columns containing more than one `.`, so none of the cases leads to a solution.